# Maven tries to use wrong groupId for license-maven-plugin

Tags: maven

I am trying to add [mycila version](https://oss.carbou.me/license-maven-plugin/#goals) of maven-license-plugin to the root module of a legacy project:

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>com.mycila</groupId>
    <artifactId>license-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3</version>
    <configuration>...</configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>format</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
```

When I try to run it with command `mvn license:format`, I get error `Could not find goal 'format' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo:license-maven-plugin:2.4.0 among available goals`.

There is no `org.codehaus.mojo` version of `license-maven-plugin` defined anywhere in my workspace. In fact, the word `codehaus` is not present in any of the pom.xmls within the workspace.

None of my modules find `codehaus` in their dependency hierarchy, and if I run `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.6.3:resolve-plugins`, the only listed `license-maven-plugin` dependency is for `com.mycila`, as expected. There are some `org.codehaus.plexus` dependencies on that list, but no `org.codehaus.mojo`.

If I delete all `codehaus` dependencies from my local .m2 directory, running `mvn license:format` re-downloads both `license-maven-plugin` and `mojo-parent`, and later `animal-sniffer-parent` and `animal-sniffer-annotations` appear as well.

If I run `mvn license:format` with `-X` it tells me `[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix license from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]`, the word `mycila` doesn't appear anywhere within the logs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem is that the legacy project has a bit weird structure. The root module pom.xml has `<modules>` listed, but those modules don't have the root module defined as their parent. Because the listed modules get resolved before the root module, and they don't have any `license-maven-plugin` defined, they try to fall back to the `codehaus` version without throwing any error about the missing definition. And then the build fails before ever reaching the root module that does have the plugin definition.

It's not quite clear to me *why* the `org.codehaus.mojo` gets picked as an option for resolving the goal prefix, it's certainly not inherited from the [super-pom](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.9.5/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html). I don't have time to dig deeper into this right now, but clearly it does happen.

Removing the `<modules>`, moving the `<modules>` definition to a different profile, or defining the plugin in each module does the trick. Presumably so would do making the root module an actual parent module for each module, but that's not currently possible in my project for unrelated reasons.